# how to detect logical and string index in sub-list and delete it

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, types

I have a list like this:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],[1,1,2,4],[1,2,3,False],[1,False,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,'word'],[5,6,7,8],[1,4,3,4],[True,1,2,4],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0],[False,False,False,False]]
```

and I want as output a list like this:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],[1,1,2,4],[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,4,3,4],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]
```

I just want to delete or remove a any list. it have member of string or logical. 
how i can do it.

Comment: So you want to remove any lists that have `False` in them?

Comment: yeap, I want to remove any type is not int or float from list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this with list comprehension where we perform a filter with `any(..)` that checks if there is any element that is an instance of `str` or `bool`:

```
[sublist for sublist in A if not any(isinstance(e, (str, bool)) for e in sublist)]
```

this then yields:

```
>>> [sublist for sublist in A if not any(isinstance(e, (str, bool)) for e in sublist)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 4, 3, 4], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: what is meaning of e ?

Comment: @lyca: the element in the generator, it enumerates over `sublist` with `... for e in sublist`.